# Как обновить существующую запись с помощью ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: sql, insert

Здравствуйте!

Сегодня впервые столкнулся с `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` не до конца понял как он работает.

Делаю запрос

```
DB()->query("INSERT INTO ". BB_BT_USER_STATS ."
    (topic_id,  user_id, date_comleted)
    SELECT
    topic_id, user_id, ". TIMENOW ." 
    FROM tmp_users_stats
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    date_comleted = что тут писать");
```

В итоге хочу получить обновление в таблице если `topic_id` и `user_id` уже существуют(уникальные), а `date_comleted` отличается  иначе создается новая строка с новыми данными.

Comment: раз есть знак равенства - константу, скорее всего дату. А какую - такую что б записи отличались, такую как вам нужно.

Comment: Если в случае дубликата вам нужно вставить строку, а не обновить поле, то возможно вам нужно on duplicate key **insert**? Может этот топик вам поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884344/mysql-on-duplicate-key-insert-into-an-audit-or-log-table

Answer (score 3):

Например, в MySQL, для того, чтобы извлечь значение из INSERT-данных, следует воспользоваться функцией `VALUES()`

```
DB()->query("INSERT INTO ". BB_BT_USER_STATS ."
    (topic_id,  user_id, date_comleted)
    SELECT
    topic_id, user_id, ". TIMENOW ." 
    FROM tmp_users_stats
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    date_comleted = VALUES(date_comleted)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Если topic_id + user_id уникальны, то можно использовать REPLACE TO вместо INSERT TO , в этом случае запись перезапишется в случае существования или создастся новая, если таких ключей раньше не было. Только надо учесть, что в случае REPLACE, старая запись удалится, а потом вставится новая с теми же ключами. Если существуют constraints с действиями ON DELETE CASCADE, то данные могут погибнуть