# помощь с ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте!
Сегодня впервые столкнулся с `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` не до конца понял как он работает.

Делаю запрос

```
DB()->query("INSERT INTO ". BB_BT_USER_STATS ."
    (topic_id,  user_id, date_comleted)
    SELECT
    topic_id, user_id, ". TIMENOW ." 
    FROM tmp_users_stats
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    date_comleted = что тут писать");
```

В итоге хочу получить обновление в таблице если `topic_id` и `user_id` уже существуют(уникальные), а `date_comleted` отличается  иначе создается новая строка с новыми данными.

Comment: Помоему это копия вопроса, который уже задавался Алекс31 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556425

Comment: Такм и есть. Писал вопрос через приложение на смартфоне. После нажатия на Отправить вопрос, приложение меня не перекинуло на сам вопрос... через некоторое время я еще раз нажал на отправить вопрос... так и получился дубль вопрос